# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 with delete where in mysql query using nodejs mysql2

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-mysql2

I'm using mysql2/promise to execute some database queries in my node script (AWS lambda function). I want to perform a delete where in query to delete multiple rows, but no matter how I bind the value I always seem to get the same error of "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

My simplified code looks like this:

```
const userIds = [45549, 46207];
const deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN (?)";
return await pool.query(deleteQuery, [userIds]);
```

I've tried different things to bind the value, i.e.:

```
return await pool.query(deleteQuery, [userIds.map(id => [id]]);
```

```
return await pool.query(deleteQuery, userIds.map(id => [id]);
```

But nothing seems to work. How am I supposed to bind an array value to a WHERE IN query?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This is an `INSERT` error, which should not be happening during `DELETE`, unless there's a trigger.

Check if you have any `DELETE` triggers on your `user` table, and if these triggers are performing any malformed `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thanks, turns out you were right. There was a BEFORE DELETE trigger in place, which stored the deleted row data to a backup table. The backup table was missing one column.